# How can I get Flutter material icon dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the name for the icon returned from the api, for example like this:

```
{
  "iconName": "home"
}
```

So i want to display it in my application:

```
 icon: Icon(Icons.home)
```

But this icon can be any from the [Icons class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html), so I don't want to make a helper class or HashMap to handle this.

Is there anyway to do this with reflection like in Java, or some better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok for now I implemented a Map for this. If anyone need it, it can be find [here](https://github.com/djokobozinov/FlutterIconsHelper).